# joomla 3 php if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following statement in my Joomla 3 index.php file that I am trying to work out:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
<?php if( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) == 'article' ): ?>
  <div class="col-md-<?php echo $right; ?>">
    <section class="sidebar right-sidebar">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="standard" />
    </section>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need to change the above statement so that the following happens:

**Scenario 1**

If nothing in the right position, remove all divs completely

**Scenario 2**

If module in the right position show module, but only on article pages - ***not*** on blog category page

PHP newbie - how would I do this statement?

Comment: first scenario can be accomplished using js code or jquery lib , i don think its possible via php

Comment: this is really for a Joomal person... scenario 1 is completely possible using Joomla, but I need to incorporate scenario 2 also - both are do-able separately, but I need them as one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
<?php if( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) == 'article' || $this->countModules('right') ): ?>
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $right; ?>">
        <section class="sidebar right-sidebar">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="standard" />
        </section>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```